# Neo4j: How to do order-insensitive equality test of 2 lists?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have nodes which has these properties:

```
name: abc
colors: [red,green,blue]
```

Where the colors property is a list which can contain any number of elements in any order.

I want to create a query that will find nodes which have a colors property containing all the elements of another list, `[red,green,yellow,blue]` for example.

How would I write this query?

I know you can do something like `MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.colors = [red,green,yellow,blue]`, but this will only match nodes which have those list of colors in that exact order. I want a query which checks that a node's color property contains the specified colors, in any order.

Something like

```
myColors = [red,green,yellow,blue]
match = true
for each color in node.colors:
  if color not in myColors:
    // DO NOT MATCH
    match = false
```

But as a valid cypher query

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-all) predicate function to do an order-insensitive equality test of 2 lists:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE ALL(c IN n.colors WHERE c IN [red,green,yellow,blue])
...
```